# How to use jQuery scripts withing ExtJS panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have a scenario where I am having my header created using jQuery & that header is being loaded in ExtJS. For the same I am using the below code.

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    autoHeight  : true,
    html : <Some HTML code containing jquery scripts> 
});
```

But for some unknown reasons my header scripts are not working.

Only HTML is being rendered. Also there is no error long on console.

Any suggestions will be quite helpful.

Comment: You are using a framework. then I am not sure why you are also using jQuery. :/

Comment: I support, two monsters in one window. :-)

Comment: @Mr_Green,@Damask Actually I have to include an existing jQuery header in my EXT-JS page.

Comment: @HemantKumar Did you check my answer below? let me know if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    autoHeight  : true,
    html : function(){
        return <Some HTML code containing jquery scripts> 
    }()
});
```

**or**

```
panel.update = <Some HTML code containing jquery scripts>;
```

Comment: its not working. Well I am trying to trace to problem. Will keep you informed.

Answer (score -1):

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisramakers/ZXDru/)

You can add listener as follows and use what ever js or jquery you want,
see example

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    frame: true,
    title: 'Test panel',
    height: 250,
    listeners: {
        render: function(){

            // this.body.dom is the raw dom object of the body element of this panel
            // render your plot to this.body.dom
            //write js / jquery

            console.log(this.body.dom)
            this.body.update('This is the new content');
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: @Mr_Green Same question in my mind also . . . its knowledge n will not be waste . .  .      :)